# Selecting multiple checking boxes with FormHelper in CakePHP

Tags: forms, cakephp

So in an Index view for a certain model, I'm including some checkboxes; I have an array of days of the week, and so have 7 checkboxes available, per record.

I can save data, no problem. What I can't figure out is how to pre-select the checkboxes, based on each record's saved data. Currently I'm having to do this:

```
<?php if ( isset($user['SurveyAssignment'][0]['active_days']['Monday']) && $user['SurveyAssignment'][0]['active_days']['Monday'] == 1 ) { $monChecked = true; } else { $monChecked = false; } ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('SurveyAssignment.' . $count .'.active_days.Monday', array('type' => 'checkbox', 'label' => false, 'div' => false, 'checked' => $monChecked));?>
```

And that's just for ONE day, for one record. Right now, I'm doing that 7 times, for each record. It's very bloated.

I would have thought I could just read in the array for each record, and select a group of checkboxes accordingly.

I'm sure I'm missing something very simple but I can't see past my nose at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

If your associations are set up correctly, your field name is correct, and you're passing the correct data, they will be selected automatically for you.

The likely answer is you're not using the correct field or Model.field for your form input.

Comment: The issue is that the days of the week are stored in an array, which is serialized and stored in a db field. I unserialize before doing anything with it, but the days themselves are not part of the model's structure. Will that cause a problem?

Comment: That will cause you to not be able to use Cake's automagic, and force you to do code like you currently are doing.